# Count nested item before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, cocoon-gem

Let have Order and Item models.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :delete_all

  before_save do
    self.packed_volume = compute_packed_volume
  end

  private

  def compute_packed_volume
    items.count * 0.1O
  end
end
```

And

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :items
end
```

The problem is that items.count is equals to 0 since items are not yet created.
How can we get the number of items that will be created to used it when we create an order?

Comment: Why do you need to use before save not after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `size` instead, it won't run a query

```
items.size * 0.1O
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a "counter cache". It implements exactly what you're trying to do. ActiveRecord can do this for you:

```
belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

There are a couple of gems that do this, updating a count field in the parent record whenever a child record is created or deleted.

Gem `counter-cache` does the job simply. Another, `counter-culture` takes it a bit further, including support for counting children in `has_many :through` relationships.

Your example is a little more interesting, as you're not looking for the count, but a computation on the count. So, you could either just roll with that and use it to compute the packed_volume on the fly, probably in a method on the model very similar to your `compute_packed_volume()` method.

If you wanted to store the actual volume in your parent record (perhaps it is very expensive to compute), you need to shift from putting callbacks on the parent model to putting them on the child model. The `counter_culture` gem supports that with its "Delta Magnitude". Something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  counter_culture :order, column_name: :packed_volume, delta_magnitude: 0.1
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

The `delta_magnitude` parameter can take a proc, so you can do more complicated things. Perhaps something like this:

```
counter_culture :order, column_name: :packed_volume, delta_magnitude: -> {|item| item.length * item.width * item.height }
```

You could roll your own solution along these lines if you have other requirements that preclude using a gem. You'll need to add callbacks to Item for `after_create` and `before_destroy` to increment/decrement the parent record. You may also need to update the order when the record is changed, if your volume computation becomes more complicated.